# Restricting free text entry in jquery auto complete widget upon enter button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application. I have only a textbox in one of the pages and its actually an jquery auto complete widget. I have  MVC5 "Required" data annotation for the field which is bound to the textbox. Very near to the textbox, there is a hyper link which act as the submit button. Upon clicking this hyper link I submit the form like $("#myform").submit(). This will call the form action method and will return a new View from the controller action method. Validation is working fine too. But there is one problem when you click enter button, it will submit the value which is not a an auto complete suggestion. I have handled the change event of the auto complete widget like below.

```
 $('#selectedPlace').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            predictUsingGoogle(request, response);
        },
        // Sets the selected value to text box
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#selectedPlace').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#selectedPlaceID').val(ui.item.value);
            $("#searchBtn").focus();
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#selectedPlace").val(ui.item.label);
        },
        change: function(event,ui)
        {
            if (ui.item == null) {
                $("#selectedPlace").val('');
                $("#selectedPlace").focus();
            }
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
```

This will help me to avoid the free text entry upon clicking the hyper link button, but it's not helping me in enter button click. Can someone please advise me here?

Comment: is that autocomplete from jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes. It is from jQuery